# How can I count aggs group in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm writing some queries in Elastic search to count some events in an index. I think I have the right construct but while I can get the search results from an aggs group, actually I want a count, not the results.

My background is SQL and the equivalent query I am trying to perform would be:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(1) as volume
FROM (
      SELECT
      key
    , type
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY key ORDER BY timestamp DESC ) AS instance
  FROM event
  ) A
WHERE type != 'Delete'
AND instance = 1
```

In plain English, this is: count the volume of events for the latest event by key, excluding deletes

I have tried the following Elastic:

```
GET /index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_key": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "key",
        "size": 1000000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_record_per_group": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "timestamp": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "type": "Delete"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

...and this does indeed return what I expect. I am aware of the count API and know that it does not support aggs.

Can anyone help point out the bit I am missing and, hopefully, show me the most efficient way to get the value for volume only (i.e. no other results)?

Thanks in advance

edit:

A worked example would be

```
key type    timestamp   latest? include?
1   insert  00:00:01    
1   update  00:00:02        
2   insert  00:00:03        
3   insert  00:00:04    Y       Y
2   delete  00:00:05    Y       N
4   insert  00:00:06        
1   update  00:00:07    Y       Y
4   update  00:00:08    Y       Y

volume: 3
```

Comment: If you get a count, I think you dont need the criteria order latest event by key.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only count you can use the value count aggs.

I would also use a filter to improve the cache and improve the performance of the query.

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "type": "Delete"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "count_volume": {
      "value_count": {
        "field": "key"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I need the top hits with a size 1 otherwise my events are double counted

Comment: Out of curiosity, does this method of filtering get applied before or after aggs?